# Counter-clockwise iOS CircleLayout

Tags: ios, layout, uicollectionview

I'm using slightly modified version of Apple's CircleLayout from WWDC found here: https://github.com/mpospese/CircleLayout.

My current code draws the first element at the top and then lays out the rest in a clockwise fashion. How can I use this code so the layout starts with the first element at the top and draws the next elements counter-clockwise along the path? My trigonometry is a bit rusty.

I believe the portion of code that needs changing is:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:path];
    attributes.size = CGSizeMake(ITEM_SIZE, ITEM_SIZE);
    attributes.center = CGPointMake(_center.x + _radius * cosf(2 * path.item * M_PI / _cellCount - M_PI / 2),
                                    _center.y + _radius * sinf(2 * path.item * M_PI / _cellCount - M_PI / 2));
    return attributes;
}
```

Current:

[image]

Desired:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing an angle by its negative value changes the orientation. In your case

```
attributes.center = CGPointMake(_center.x + _radius * cosf(-2 * path.item * M_PI / _cellCount - M_PI / 2),
                                _center.y + _radius * sinf(-2 * path.item * M_PI / _cellCount - M_PI / 2));
```

should to the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the negative value when opposite direction is desired.